# How find bin directory in ASP.NET Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

My EF project is in one project and my ASP.NET Core project in another project ,

D:\AspProjects\DatabaseHafez>        <=== my ef model is in this folder

D:\AspProjects\Hafez>                <=== my aspnet core 3 is in this folder

so each project has one bin folder.

The below builder(ConfigurationBuilder) should have the path of appsettings.json file for reading connections string.so the below has this path =>

D:\AspProjects\DatabaseHafez\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\appsettings.json

but my appsettins.json file in my asp.net core project so after bulilding is will copy to output folder   =>

D:\AspProjects\Hafez\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\appsettings.json

so How can i find the output folder path?

```
public class AppDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<AppDbContext>
{
    AppDbContext IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<AppDbContext>.CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);

        IConfigurationRoot configuration = builder.Build();

        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AppDbContext>();

        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));

        var context = new AppDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);

        context.Database.EnsureCreated();
        return context;
    }
}
```

Now I want to add migrations But I get an error

```
D:\AspProjects\DatabaseHafez>dotnet ef migrations add changed98112601  

Build started...  
Build succeeded.
```

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The configuration file 'appsettings.json' was not found and is not optional. The physical path is 'D:\AspProjects\DatabaseHafez\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\appsettings.json'.
>
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.HandleException(ExceptionDispatchInfo info)
>   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load(Boolean reload)
>   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load()
>   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot..ctor(IList`1 providers)
>
>   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
>
>   at DatabaseHafez.AppDbContextFactory.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<DatabaseHafez.AppDbContext>.CreateDbContext(String[] args) in D:\AspProjects\DatabaseHafez\AppDbContextFactory.cs:line 27
>
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContextFromFactory(Type factory)
>
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.<>c__DisplayClass13_1.<FindContextTypes>b__9()
>
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.b__0()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
>
> The configuration file 'appsettings.json' was not found and is not optional. The physical path is 'D:\AspProjects\DatabaseHafez\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\appsettings.json'.

Now I want to know how can I find the `bin` folder of my ASP.NET Core project?

Comment: you want to know how to programmatically find bin folder ?

Comment: can you confirm if the problem is solved, if not let me know, I can help out :)

Comment: @Clint your answer didn't help me.my asp core project and ef core project are in separate project.in above code in my ef core project,I want read connection string from `appsettins.json` file that is in another project in my asp.net core project .so how can I find path of `appsettins.json` ? For now I deleted `configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")` and inserted the connection string .but this work is not correct way.

Comment: You can try this from efcore project and refer your appsettings in .net core. `var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()             .SetBasePath("D:\AspProjects\Hafez\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\appsettings.json")
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

Comment: hope you were able set the appsettings path using the above code ?

Comment: @Clint I couldn't use this ,because if I upload my project to host,It will not work anymore

Comment: yes exactly, I just wanted to show you that you can use SetBasePath to solve this problem

Answer (score 18):

Try to get it line this:

```
var runDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)
```

`GetCurrentDirectory` might also work, but there is this bug here: https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/589 so I would avoid it.

Comment: This gives \bin\net5.0 instead of \bin

Answer (score 8):

For .net core, you can use `PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath` of nuget pkg `Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions`

This resolves for any runtime whether it be an web app or a test runtime.

From .Net5+ use `AppContext.BaseDirectory` which supercedes the above.

see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appcontext.basedirectory?view=net-7.0#system-appcontext-basedirectory

Comment: The package has been deprecated and no longer maintained

Answer (score 5):

You need to get the current directory.

```
Directory.GetParent(typeof(Program).Assembly.Location).FullName;
```

This will return the correct directory.

Answer (score -1):

Another way to find `bin` directory is to use [`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.basedirectory?view=net-5.0).

This property returns directory for current loaded domain.